# xunit.net - check if running from Visual studio

Tags: xunit.net

I have a unit test that needs to be run only from visual studio. How can check in a xunit test if it is running from Visual Studio? Can i somehow check the running process?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your test, you can add a `[Trait("Category","VisualStudio")]` attribute.

It will still run in visual studio.

When you launch the test command line, you can add the following (assuming you are using .Net Core):

dotnet test --filter Category!=VisualStudio

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests#xunit (the rest of the documentation provides help if you are using xunit command line)